# Will Ubuntu 14.04 support WUBI? Or will another alternate Windows Installer be available? (not 13.04, 13.10)

Tags: windows, wubi

Will **Ubuntu 14.04** support WUBI? Or will another alternate Windows Installer be available? I work on a lab network with PC Devices which *ETH and USB hardware has been removed*, and we use a different bus technology. Wubi was the only way to install Ubuntu, so we are waiting for Wubi to be updated for the next LTS release.

We appreciate your advice and thank you for your help.
-Bran

Comment: Seems to me as a question for Nostradamus but I will not vote it for closing because I want to see if any official answers exit.

Comment: Please check the link for a better understanding of what's happening https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2013-April/036993.html

Comment: It is not duplicate. It meant by Ubuntu 14.04 and the question regarded is talking about 13.04.

Comment: Answer to your q: http://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts/449526#449526