# Problems in Upgrading 12.04 to 14.04 which is 64bit wubi application?

Tags: upgrade, 14.04

I'm on 12.04 currently I want to upgrade to trusty. I'm using wubi 64bit application and people said that there might be problems for 64 bit regarding grub menu. Is there a chance that I might lose windows (I'm using 8.1 pro)?

Comment: Wubi is not supported any more in newer versions of Ubuntu. It does not work with new computers that hhave UEFI and pre-installed Windows 8 (and above). I recommend: back up all your data (both in Windows and Ubuntu). Uninstall Ubuntu 12.04 (WUBI) from within Windows. Do a full install of 14.04 directly, by booting from a Live USB/DVD. Restore your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LTS upgrades of Ubuntu is not enabled yet and won't be until July 24th 2014. Wubi is also not supported anymore, so you might want to do a proper install and migrate your data to it. This is usually quite easy, because all your data and settings are in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

what Jo-Erlend posted is not entirely true (at least not in my case), i just did the upgrade yesterday and when i typed the command:

> sudo do-release-upgrade --check-dist-upgrade-only --devel-release

it gave me the option to upgrade to 14.04 lts (i was using 12.04 lts)

however, i did encounter mayor problems after the upgrade (missing files, could not log in, etc)

Thankfully i had a backup, so i opted for an bootable USB with 14.04 and it all went perfect, no more issues, but Jo-Erlend is right, Wubi is not supported anymore

My advice, if you want to upgrade, back up your info and install 14.04 via USB (it will give you the choice of replacing completely the previous Ubuntu 12.04 version)