# Is it safe to upgrade Wubi install from 12.04LTS to 14.04LTS?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, wubi

I have 12.04LTS installed in wubi and want to know if and how I can upgrade to 14.04LTS.
I do not want a new installation, as that would totally disrupt my current activities and programming.

Comment: Canonical stopped supporting Wubi recently - there are some suggestions that the program may still work, but if you run into difficulties then support may be lacking.

Comment: Support continues for 12.04 only. It may work with newer version but you need to be very knowledgeable and be able to support yourself. http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7497/wubi-discussion-again-supported-here-on-ask-ubuntu-13-04-and-later/7596#7596

Comment: Problems have been reported: _" i did encounter mayor problems after the upgrade (missing files, could not log in, etc)"_ and _"I can no longer boot into Ubuntu. When I try to, I see the message mount:mounting..."etc, then "Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init"._ http://askubuntu.com/questions/453651/problems-in-upgrading-12-04-to-14-04-which-is-64bit-wubi-application http://askubuntu.com/questions/450117/cant-boot-wubi-after-upgrading-to-14-04-from-12-04

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install

Answer (score -2):

Simply running `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` from the terminal prompt will take care of it for you. Try to run it from the console on the computer you're upgrading, since if you do it via a terminal session from another system (via ssh or something similar) if the upgrade has issues, or your connection drops, recovering could be problematic.

It worked for me, but not before without issues, as my ssh session timed out multiple times duing the upgrade.  I discovered the best way to handle it was to run screen, then run the `do-release-upgrade -d` from within [`screen`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/screen.1.html), that way, if you do loose your connection, a simple screen -d will give you back your previous screens, all nice and orderly as they should be.

I did the 12.04 LTS upgrade to 14.04 LTS, but then (accidentally) wound upgrading again to the latest unicorn release too, as I wound typing `do-release-upgrade -d` again, with my scrollback buffer, so now I'm running a full-blown test release, and having issues, but that's not the fault of the initial `do-release-upgrade` run.

I hope this helps.