# "No init found" error after upgrading to 14.04

Tags: boot

Please, I have installed UBUNTU 14.04 on my netbook, that already had UBUNTU 12.04. When the up grade was completed, and after the restart, appears the following mesagge:

```
mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on /root failed: Invalid argumento mount:
mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory mount:
mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory mount:
mounting proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory Target
filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init. No init found. Try passing
init= bootarg.


BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built in suelo (así) Entre  'help' for a list of built-in commands
```

What can I do?

Comment: Edit the title of your question so it summarizes your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Boot from the Ubuntu Live CD and open a Terminal

Run `sudo fdisk -l` to get the device name. You'll get something like:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes 
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: **********

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sda1 * 1 30238 242886703+ 83 Linux
/dev/sda2 30239 30401 1309297+ 5 Extended
/dev/sda5 30239 30401 1309266 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

In this case, Ubuntu is installed in `/dev/sda1`. So type:

```
sudo fsck /dev/sda1
```

Restart the system and boot normally.

Comment: This is not always the case, the initramfs capable of checking it first right before using it.

Answer (score 0):

The `mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on /root failed` suggests this was originally a Wubi installation, in which Linux is stored within a large file on your Windows system.  This would mean you accessed Linux from the Windows Boot Manager.  This is no longer officially supported.

See [Can't boot Wubi after upgrading to 14.04 from 12.04: "Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450117/cant-boot-wubi-after-upgrading-to-14-04-from-12-04-target-filesystem-doesnt) for workarounds to boot Linux.

In the longer term, however, it would be best to make a fresh installation in which Windows and Linux are on separate parts of the disk.