# Ubuntu and Windows on one hdd drive

Tags: windows, 14.04

Lately was the release of Ubuntu 14.04. I was using 12.04 on my laptop but it was installed with wubi installer. I tried to search for a wubi with 14.04 but didn't find it. Can Is there a way to install 14.04 alongside Windows 7 on one HDD. I had and idea to to upgrade 12.04 to 14.04 but I don't know will this work. Any ideas ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows installer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met a lot of people that had some serious problem after upgrading to 14.04. So I recommend you to do a clean installation (after saving your data !) or to keep 12.04.

Here is how I did a clean install (adapt for yourself) :

1. I downloaded the ubuntu x64 iso (choose depending your CPU) (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
2. I used lili usb creator from windows to make a bootable usb key. (http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)
   USE 2.0 USB KEY AND PORT, 3.0 WONT WORK.
3. I started on the live usb (choose try ubuntu)
4. Using Gparted, I made these partitions (sda3 to sda7 are one ubuntu installation) :

   /dev/sda1   *        2048   524290047   262144000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

   /dev/sda2       524290048  1500540927   488125440    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

   /dev/sda3      1500542974  1953523711   226490369    5  Extended

   /dev/sda5      1500542976  1668314460    83885742+  83  Linux

   /dev/sda6      1668317184  1701871615    16777216   82  Linux swap / Solaris

   /dev/sda7      1701873664  1953523711   125825024   83  Linux
5. I launched installation, choose other (custom installation)
6. I used sda5 as /, sda7 as /home.
7. You can guess how to end the installation. If you install windows afterwards, remember to use boot-repair.

I recommend you to put your Ubuntu installation at the end of the disk. This way, it will be easier to increase extended partition size using unused space of previous partition.

Comment: Will this really work ? I don't loose data I have on my windows

Comment: I did many installations (20 or more?) using this. It will work. And as you're using windows 7, it will be really easy. Just don't touch the windows partition. The first time you will boot Windows 7 after the installation, it will do chkdsk, don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS. Open `Software Updater` and let it check for all updates. When it is done, it should inform you that there is a new version of Ubuntu available, and give you an option to upgrade.

If not, check the `Software & Updates` under the *Updates* tab there is a dropdown list at the bottom for *Notify Me Of New Ubuntu Versions*; select **Long Term Support versions** and then exit the window. Restart `Software Updater` let it run again. You should now be informed of a new version which you may upgrade to.

Answer (score -1):

Wubi isn't no longer available (what I've heard on the Forums a time ago).

It is more advisable to set up a normal dual boot system; 
you'll get:

- increased performance
- more stable Ubuntu
- a handy way to fix W7 should a problem occur
- a very easy way to handle files fromout 2 operating systems

To be short: Wubi was a way to install Ubuntu alongside Windows, but it is vunerable since Windows can have its issues what could lead that you can't bootup your Ubuntu. 
So, a dual boot with separate partitions is a more plausible way of working with Ubuntu.

The installer is very easy to use, and choosing partition-sizes is also very easy. Please refer to the Wiki of Ubuntu should extra help be nessecary.

Succes!

Comment: Re: `Wubi isn't no longer available...`: [not so](http://askubuntu.com/a/449526/38585). That link has plenty of additional relevant information for this Q&A.