# Install 14.04 LTS from 11.04

Tags: 12.04, 11.04, windows-7, 14.04, lts

I have ubuntu 11.04 installed in my PC. Now, the system does not allow me to update or upgrade anything. So, I would like to use one of your LTS version. I prefer 14.04, as it is new. I am having a dual booting PC with ubuntu 11.04 and windows-7. I want to remove ubuntu 11.04 and in its place I would like to install 14.04. So, kindly suggest me how can I proceed with installation.

Comment: this still is valid: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu just s+r 11.10 for 14.04 :)

Answer (score 0):

You should have done more search as there are thousands of guides to do that on the internet. But here is my [answer to the question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456999/ubuntu-and-windows-on-one-hdd-drive/457004#457004)

Comment: I did not understand... I am new to this....