# Can't get Ubuntu to install in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, system-installation

I saw Ubuntu today on my friend's laptop, and I immediately fell in love. I then decided to try installing Ubuntu reading the guide on the official Ubuntu website (which included downloading an `.iso` image and setting it up for booting from my USB drive). After attempting for five hours, I have still not been able to install Ubuntu.

I use an HP Envy M6 with an existing installation of Windows 8.

## Things I have tried:

- Disabling `Secure Boot` in the BIOS
- Disabling fast booting in Windows 8
- Changing the boot order in the BIOS so that the USB boots first (causing a BSOD, which I eventally solved)
- Using the [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) tool to create my bootable USB (from the `.iso` image I downloaded earlier)

This has really been frustrating. I had thought the whole process would be as easy I read on the official Ubuntu website.

Comment: at what step you get problem? do u get boot loder screen

Comment: Could you provide us a photos of bios screen and booting order? Thanks!

Comment: You can also try using CD instead of USB. Also, if you cannot get ubuntu to install, try installing it inside windows, by running wubi.exe in USB.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, I really didn't take any pictures of my pc's bios settings but here's what has been happening, everytime I restart my pc in advanced start up mode to have it allow me choose to boot from my usb, it keeps booting back into windows. I have no idea what I did wrong. @Milosevic .. Where do I find wubi.exe ?

Comment: @Aditi-K I can't see anything Ubuntu on startup of my pc asking me to install anything, my PC just boots right back to windows every time I restart it.

Comment: @Feyisayo still problem in BIOS setting ..I had same problem .So please connect your USB and restart PC/LAPTOP .press for BIOS setting check whether your USB got detected (ex: transcent JET flash) this is how your usb should get detected by its name select that and save exit..boot again

Comment: For dual boot, try following the method shown [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/tired-of-windows-8-how-to-dual-boot-windows-ubuntu/). Wubi is not currently working in Windows 8/8.1. you have create a partion or resize an existing one. Follow the manual method from the above link

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: Hi. I'm sure I've got the 64-bit iso file. And I also took a picture of my bios' at the boot device options screen. http://imgur.com/aqFMs0j

Comment: Wubi.exe is a installation file located in your flash drive, if you used pen drive tool to create bootable USB. It installs ubuntu inside windows, but it's kinda like dual boot except when you delete windows, ubuntu is also gone.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry,  Wubi is discontinued. Didn't know that...

Comment: Have you tried using CD? How did you install windows?

Comment: No I don't have access to any CD or DVD's right now :( .. And windows came as the stock OS from my PC's manufacturer HP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case, someone stumbles on this kind of issue installing Ubuntu with an existing installation of UEFI Windows 8,  I finally got Ubuntu installed by using a DVD instead.

I came across this solution by reading a comment on some forum where someone had the same issue starting installation from a USB just like me, I think the issue is with Windows 8 not playing nicely with USB drives on start-up.

I got myself a dvd, burnt the ubuntu iso image on it with [InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/?page_id=5) and restarted my pc, then chose to boot from the DVD from my PC's boot device options and the installation process was smooth.

I didn't even have Legacy Mode enabled which wasn't the case when I was trying to install from a USB.

Before I decided to use a LiveDVD, I would have to enable Legacy mode in my PC's BIOS before I can get options to boot from a USB, which still never worked though.

So I'll recommend anyone out there trying to install Ubuntu from a USB with issues to also give installing from a LiveDVD a shot before giving up on the whole process. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have problem not with installing the system per se, but with starting installation.

If you're sure, you've disabled fastboot, you need to get to "boot menu".

Before windows start kicks in you probably see either full screen HP logo, or some hardware information - look for information that reads "Boot menu - [KEY]".
Then press that before Windows starts. you should be presented with menu where you'll be able to choose a device you want to boot from (usual suspects are keys F2, F11, F12 and DEL).

Now, you might get 2 options for the USB drive - UEFI and some other (it might be named "old", "standard" or something else. But you'll most probably want to use the one that starts with UEFI (thats - in short - the way the drives will be accessed).

After that you should be able to start *ubuntu installer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a 32-bit or a 64-bit ISO?  My laptop refused to boot from the USB and when I switched to a 64-bit ISO it worked just fine

Answer (score -1):

If you want to install it alongside windows 8, you can just use `WUBI.exe` which is in the iso file (it installs it inside windows' partition, in folder `C:\Ubuntu` if you won't change it.

Comment: I advise against this, as [Wubi is discontinued](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SaucySalamander/ReleaseNotes#Ubuntu_downloader_for_Windows_discontinued).

Comment: But there's Wubi in Ubuntu 14.04..

Comment: Check [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/449526/223688) concerning the status of Wubi. Yes, it is officially still supported; it ships with Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise), and Precise has more than three years of support. It is also still contained on all ISOs of later Ubuntu versions (except 13.04). But it has some [severe issues](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2013-April/036993.html) (*particularly* with Windows 8), and its use is discouraged nowadays.

Comment: Hmm.. After hours of misery trying to get ubuntu installed on my PC, do you guys suggest I try earlier versions of ubuntu, 13.0.4 maybe?  The entire installation procedure has taken so much of my time, I'm this close to giving up on the whole process.