# Will Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or later Wubi installer be returing

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, wubi, bios

will Wubi Instaler ever be returning in ubuntu 14.04 or later i have a friend that really wants ubuntu and is upset becuase he cant figure out how to create a partition on his hp pavilion g6 64bit laptop. i have tried many times to help him but i can not figure out how to boot form a live USB on his version of BIOS. His version of BIOS is Insyde H20. despite i did it on my computer and have a successfull dual-boot with windows 8.1 64 bit and ubuntu 14.04 64 bit with a similar BIOS Version. I would also really appreciate if ubuntu.com could bring back the older Wubi installer throught the ISO file and just upgrade ubuntu manually once installed.

I really appreciated yur time and i hope Wubi will be brought Back.

Comment: Your* I misspelled your

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows installer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for you, but there are no plans at all about reintroducing Wubi, so the answer is no

Comment: but you could boot the live session from dvd

Comment: Got any sources though?

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/wubi-advice

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_(Ubuntu_installer)

Comment: @ed0 should your comments be [edit]ed into your answer (then all comments removed)?  Might you clean up the question with a suggested edit?