# Wubi not working lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, wubi

I am trying to install lubuntu 14.04 using wubi. I have already compared the md5 of the image lubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso with the one given at UbuntuHashes and it matched. I also burnt the image to a pendrive and used the live system. So, the image file I downloaded can be assumed to be not corrupted but I still get the error : Cannot download the metalink and therefore the iso. I have googled a lot and nearly tried out all the methods mentioned there but still unable to install the wubi. Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows installer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onwards](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wubi was discontinued as of Ubuntu 13.04.  (although it was still released as part of the desktop ISO after that -and maybe still is-). Installing Ubuntu inside windows in Win8 or up will certaily fail (as per the  official [Wubiguide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)). But trying this -even if you are using windows 7 or lower- is just going to be a minefield. I recommend against it. There are alternatives, like installing a virtual machine in your windows OS (like Oracle Virtualbox), and install Ubuntu 14.04 on that.

Good luck!

Comment: I am installing it in Windows 7 64bit

Comment: It is still desuported since last year. See:
https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2013-April/036993.html

Comment: Wubi was a great technology :'( But still are there any workarounds.

Comment: Did you actualy copy the wubi.exe file off the iso to your windows system?

Comment: i ran the wubi from inside the iso using daemon tools then i ran it from my bootable pendrive then i ran it after extracting it to a folder.

Comment: I am afraid I can't be of more help, except to repeat that Wubi is not reccomneded anymore. If you still want to pusue this, the logfiles in your temp folder might tell you something about the problem. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Wubi is discontinued. While new versions of Ubuntu do still include a wubi.exe file, it has been modified to display a message asking you to perform a native installation, and will not allow you to perform a wubi installation regardless of what operating system you are using. Aside from the message it will give you two buttons "Demo and Full installation", and "Learn more". If you click on "Demo and Full installation" it will open a prompt that says "reboot required". If you click "learn more" it opens your web browser and takes you to http://www.ubuntu.com/ .

Windows XP & Wubi.exe From Ubuntu 14.04:

screenshot 1 = https://copy.com/PokOaoaUxWgr

screenshot 2 = http#s://copy.com/bZoKKBvFiJF2