# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Wubi installer

Tags: 14.04, windows, wubi

Please give me the link to the Windows installer of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: If you're talking about Wubi, then you should know it is not included on Ubuntu DVD anymore.

Comment: It also doesn't really work with uefi, so I would never suggest using it anymore.

Comment: [Windows installer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onwards](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards?lq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows installer of Ubuntu, called Wubi, is no longer developed nor included in the Ubuntu disk. You can install Ubuntu in a normal way, which is as easy as Wubi and far less trouble prone.

There is really nothing to worry about, just follow the [Ubuntu installation help](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) and everything will be OK.

If you really want to have Ubuntu inside Windows then I would recommend using virtual machine to do so. [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) is a good choice: it is free and easy to use.

Comment: will you please give me the step wise procedure for installation in my windows 7(64-Bit)??

Comment: @user293322 no, unfortunately I have never installed Ubuntu inside Windows and I don't know how to do it. I recommend to perform normal install on the separate dedicated partition, I updated my answer with a link to user-friendly help.

Answer (score 1):

I have to correct [Mikołaj Bartnicki](https://askubuntu.com/users/280493/miko%C5%82aj-bartnicki) as in a post from [Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind) from 18th April is stated that the WUBI installer is on the [14.04 ISO](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7497/wubi-discussion-again-supported-here-on-ask-ubuntu-13-04-and-later/7596#7596) and works with windows up to 7. Windows 8 and Windows ME are not supported by WUBI. The only ISO that does not have WUBI is the [13.04 version](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7497/wubi-discussion-again-supported-here-on-ask-ubuntu-13-04-and-later/7596#7596) (and that is end of life already)

However, yes, there *is* a windows installer, but ubuntu don't want you to use it because it can cause problems (That is why ubuntu has made it harder to find wubi).

Try instead to [burn a dvd](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) or [create a bootable usb stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), and boot it from there. These methods are also very easy.

Answer (score -1):

You could try "MobaLiveCD". Its not exactly the same as WUBI, but similar. Details are on their website: http://mobalivecd-en.mobatek.net/en/