# Problem installing ubuntu over Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot

I have a hp laptop and pre installed windows 8 .

I download an iso of ubuntu 14.04 lts.

When i installed it using wobi, it reboot, install and again reboot and it shows two option for boot 1 windows 8 , 2- ubuntu .

I click on ubuntu then ubuntu start and shows an error like this "serious error found while checking drive/. Press i for ignore ,s for skip mounting ,m for manual setup" . Please help me what can i do ? 
if i use bootable pendrive for install, it install on a partition of my pc's hard drive .it don't boot ? i am beginer on linux please help me

Comment: Please avoid writing all in CAPS LOCK. It can be hard to read, and is unnecessary.

Comment: STOP SHOUTING!!!

Comment: @nicael I thought it might be hypocritical to write my comment in Caps :P. Would you agree that this makes no sense? I'm going to flag it.

Comment: Wubi does not work in 14.04. It is discontinued.

Comment: I really can't understand what you are saying, the grammar is bad, and it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Wilf, have done but I don't understand a lot of it - "When i installed it using wobi, it reboot, install and again reboot" - Install twice? Not sure what they mean.

Comment: You can not install Ubuntu with Wubi if you have Windows 8 Pre-installed. Please read the provided duplicate question or do exactly what @Wilf mentions in his answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you used Wubi to install, which requires Windows to work, and is [not recommended for Windows 8](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/wubi-advice).

It would be better to use the ISO to [create a install DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows), [boot from it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD), and [install it](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop).

For installing over/beside Windows 8, you may want to refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) - it shows how to disable secure boot etc.

Comment: But does Wubi work in 14.04? I suppose it was discontinued

Comment: @Ritik - I thought it was, though [I still have a wubi.exe on a Ubuntu 14.04 disc](http://i.stack.imgur.com/exBOO.png) (iso of http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/ , it works in Windows I think).

Comment: The disc comes with Wubi, but it does not seem to work. I did try it on my Win 8.

Comment: @WILF I TRY WITH BOOTABLE USB AND I FOUND THAT I HAVE NO PARTITION ON MY HARD DISK THEN I FORMAT TWO PARTITION AND MAKE ONE PARTITION EXT2 AND OTHER SWAP SPACE .THEN IT INSTALLED AND REBBOT BUT IT BOOTED THE WINDOWS . HELP ME

Comment: @Wilf Found it! It works on Win 7 https://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards

Comment: @user296866 - you can turn the caps-lock off... see edit.

Comment: @ wilf . i try with bootable usb and i found that i have no partition  on my hard disk then i format two partition and make one of them ext2 partition and another is swap space .then ubuntu install but when reboot it start windows 8 . please help me

Comment: see the edit, i have added a link to a post that goes through and explains how to disable secure boot, configure EFI etc.