# Permission denied while i was installing ubuntu 14.04 by wubi

Tags: windows, permissions, wubi

I have faced a problem when trying to install ubuntu 14.04 version on my windows 7 os by wubi.  It say permission denied and refer to the specific folder on drive C (I make a directory of wubi and ISO file in drive D).  I failed several times while i was installing it.

I try to solve it by

1. disable my adaptor
2. make wubi.exe in the same directory with Desktop ubuntu. ISO file
3. click run wubi.exe

result

it say "Can't download metafile and therefore ISO"

or

1. click wubi.exe to download file again by bit torrent
2. wait for 2 hours at the last minute, it say "permission denied.. bar bar and show me the path"

How could i do or solve it, please help me....

Answer (score 1):

Wubi is no longer supported. See this link

[Ubuntu Forums Staff recommendations on WUBI](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2229766)

> Though WUBI (Windows-Based-Ubuntu-Installer) is included with the
>   Ubuntu ISO up to the 14.04 release it is no longer officially
>   supported by Canonical.
>
> With no active development for Wubi, there are few experienced users
>   of Ubuntu who also use wubi on this forum, and hence few here who can
>   give informed support for wubi.
>
> There are some existing resources available for those who choose to
>   use this application as a means to try Ubuntu.
>
> http://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards
>
> https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you download [Ubuntu 12.04.5](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/) iso image or Xubuntu 12.04.5 or Kubuntu 12.04.5, your choice, and also download the executable, [wubi.exe](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/wubi.exe) from the same page. Place both files in the same folder and install Ubuntu with wubi.exe, no Internet connection or additional download needed. If possible, choose another partition to install Ubuntu instead of the partition where Windows 7 is installed.

It is better this way because you will be able to use all the software that no longer work in Ubuntu 14.04.

And if you really need to make wubi.exe work with Ubuntu 14.04 you have to use a simple command after first reboot, that is after you started wubi installation in Windows and it asked you to reboot the system to continue installing Ubuntu 14.04. Basically, you have to press the key **e** at first boot prompt for Ubuntu and look for this line to edit it:

```
         linux  /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-68-generic root=UUID=B21CF9B91CF978A5 loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro
```

and replace it with

```
          linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-68-generic root=UUID=B21CF9B91CF978A5 loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk rw
```

As you can see, all that is needed is to change **ro** to **rw** after section **loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk** from that line. Next, you can press F10 to boot and hopefully, this way, Wubi will finish installing Ubuntu, but after you get there and find yourself facing your new Ubuntu desktop, you should edit the same line(s) in grub.cfg, a file which is located in ~/boot/grub/grub.cfg. To edit grub.cfg use this code in a terminal window:

```
     gksu leafpad /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

or

```
     sudo nano /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

and look for the same line:

```
   linux    /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-68-generic root=UUID=B21CF9B91CF978A5 loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro
```

and also for this line:

```
   linux    /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-68-generic root=UUID=B21CF9B91CF978A5 loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro recovery nomodeset
```

and replace **ro** with **rw** so they look like this:

```
         linux  /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-68-generic root=UUID=B21CF9B91CF978A5 loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk rw
```

and

```
          linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-68-generic root=UUID=B21CF9B91CF978A5 loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk rw recovery nomodeset
```

Once again, all you have to do is to change **ro** to **rw** after this section **loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk** so you stop experiencing problems each time when trying to boot into Ubuntu.

You can use this solution or you can simply press **e** at each boot prompt for Ubuntu and edit that line and change RO to RW every time you want to use Ubuntu. This is a very useful command since you'll be forced to upgrade your system to yet another kernel version (Update Manager will take care of that...), and after that you'll have to edit file grub.cfg again because of the new kernel and replace **ro** with **rw** again in grub.cfg.