# How can I install Xubuntu 14.04 with wubi?

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, wubi

I have two hdd's, and I want to run xubuntu on one of them and windows 7 on the other. I do not not have a USB thumbdrive unfortunately. Can I use wubi, if not what can I then use?

Comment: Thor: if you want xUbuntu on a partition that is what you call a dual boot and NOT a WUBI install. A WUBI install would be: both hdd's are installed for Windows and Ubuntu is installed inside Windows using the WUBI installer on the DVD. You are mixing 2 things here so the answer is no on this: you can not use WUBI to install xUbuntu on a partition; that is not what WUBI is made for.

Comment: @Rinzwind Consider making your comment a complete answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows installer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onwards](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use Wubi. It hasn't supported Xubuntu for a number of releases now. You shouldn't use Wubi to install even Ubuntu anymore. It's not supported properly and there isn't a Wubi.exe for 14.04.1 either.

Actually you could use Wubi, if you are some hobbyist hacker type. I've installed Xubuntu with Wubi and converted it to a "real" install. But the effort required and chance of failure isn't worth it to explain all the steps here, sorry.

So my advice is... buy a USB thumb drive. You should have one anyway as a backup/repair disk. Install Xubuntu as a normal dual boot and you'll be a lot happier in the long run.

Comment: I installed Xubuntu 14.04 last month as described in my reply up here, and all went just fine. I don't see why a so called normal installation is a must for beginners. A Wubi based install is as demanding and rewarding as a "normal" installation and there is no need to repartition the HDD which is a plus in my opinion. Personally, I don't like Xubuntu 14.04 so I've chosen Xubuntu 12.04.5 (wubi install also) because I like its extremely stable kernel. It feels like running Windows, no overheating, no cpu stress, and it truly was a nice surprise for me. Thumbs up to the guys who put it together.

Comment: @floppy Xubuntu was removed from Wubi.exe since release 12.10. So 12.04 is the only way to install it now. The question was for 14.04 so there is no Wubi install unless you are suggesting installing 12.04 and then upgrading. Also, the question clearly states having Xubuntu on one drive i.e. not a Wubi install. Another issue is that  Wubi truly is not supported. There is no wubi.exe for 14.04.1 and then there's that manual boot workaround. This is no longer a newbie tool that it used to be.

Comment: Yes, I just seen there is no Xubuntu listed in the drop-down menu of wubi installer for 14.04 version. But I rememeber I used it specifically for Xubuntu not long ago. I must edit my reply then, and sorry for arguing with you on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Xubuntu 14.04 cannot be installed with [wubi installer](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/wubi.exe) any longer. Kubuntu 14.04 can be installed with wubi though, and it might be a better choice than Xubuntu, at least as far as I am concerned, and you can choose Kubuntu instead of Xubuntu, it looks nice and it runs pretty well once you stop akonadi server and disable nepomuk search plugin. But there is a trick, you have to follow [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487428/permission-denied-while-i-was-installing-ubuntu-14-04-by-wubi) to be able to install Kubuntu 14.04 inside Windows (with wubi installer).

A far better choice would be to try the 'new' Xubuntu 12.04.5 which is an excellent distro with a very stable kernel, and this one can be installed with Wubi installer without any headaches. To do so:

Download your iso image from [this link](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/precise/daily-live/current/), choose either **precise-desktop-i386.iso** for a 32bit install if you have a 32bit Windows system, or **precise-desktop-amd64.iso** for a 64bit install if you have a 64bit Windows system.

After you download the iso image, you can download the **wubi** installer from [this link](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/), it is located right at the end of the list. Next you should create a temporary folder on your desktop that you can label **ubuntu** and place inside this new folder both the iso image that you just downloaded and the wubi installer.

And finally, you can start installing Xubuntu inside Windows by running the wubi installer from your temporary folder. You cannot use your entire hard disk (the second one) to install Xubuntu on it because you can allocate up to 30GB of space and no more when using wubi installer. So you can partition your second hard disk into one or more NTFS drives, and then choose only one of them to install Xubuntu in there.

Remember, you can use max. 30GB for Xubuntu (which is more than enough), and leave the rest of space for storing your windows data (movies, music, docs and pictures). You can even move or copy video and/or audio files that you download while using Xubuntu anywhere on your 2 hard disks and run them either from Windows or from Xubuntu.

Choose your username, a password, don't forget to also choose from the Wubi dropdown menu Xubuntu instead of Ubuntu or Kubuntu or something else. Press install and wait for the installer to copy files and create the virtual disks. At the end you'll be asked to restart your computer to finish Xubuntu installation. Reboot and wait until Xubuntu 12.04.5 is installed on your computer.