# Is it possible to install Ubuntu from ISO on virtual Windows drive instead of burning a DVD?

Tags: mount, wubi, iso

I have downloaded the ISO file of Ubuntu 14.04.1. It has Wubi (windows installer) in it. I was wondering whether I can mount the ISO file onto a virtual drive (say using OSFMount)
(http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html) and install from there rather thank burning a DVD.

VS

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows installer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onwards](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards)

Answer (score 0):

No, OSFMount will not work, because it is only software based. That means, once you shutdown Windows, the ISO will be unmounted automatically.

You will have to burn a DVD or create a bootable USB stick.

### **HOW TO CREATE A BOOTABLE USB STICK USING WINDOWS**

1. Download [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) and run it.
2. Read the license and click `I Agree`
3. From the dropdown list, select `Ubuntu` under the `--- Ubuntu 32/64 Bit ---` section.
4. Select the Ubuntu 14.04.1 ISO file you downloaded earlier (Click `Browse`)
5. Plug in your USB stick and look up it's drive letter. (E.g. H:\, I:\...)
6. Select the drive letter you just found out from the second dropdown list. If it is not shown, check the `Show all Devices (USE WITH CAUTION)` checkbox.
   **CAUTION: Do not select any other drive than the USB, as this could damage your system.**
7. Click `Create` and wait for it to finish.
8. Once done, reboot your PC and boot from the USB stick.
   If you do not boot from the USB stick automatically, enter your BIOS setup and change the boot order. Make sure that `USB` is in front of `HDD`.

Answer (score 0):

While it is technically possible, I say this only in case someone challenges yot to bet 100$ on it. It is awkward, tedious and buggy process. Create a bootable stick or better, find that empty DVD.

For someone curious, the steps are:

- create a new partition on the drive.
- use VirtualBox to create a virtual machine with real partition as disk and DVD ISO.
- Install Linux in this virtual machine.
- install EFI shell.
- reboot into this shell and use it to boot installed Linux.
- install bootloader.