# I can't find the Ubuntu installer for Windows so that I can dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, windows-7, iso

This question may be very naive and silly, but i was reading up on downloading Ubuntu on my Windows 7 device so that i could dual boot, and use programs on Windows 7, as well as use Ubuntu. This seemed like the best option for me. The article i was reading stated that for this option, the easiest thing to do was download a Windows Installer for Ubuntu. They provided a link, so clicked it, and it took me to the Desktop Download page, which i thought was the installer. I downloaded the .iso file, but realized that that wasn't what i was supposed to have downloaded. I tried to look for the Windows installer so that i can install is almost as a program, but i can't find anything. Am i looking for the right thing? If so, where is the Windows installer. If not, what do i download for the dual boot system, and what do i do, since everything I've read says not to download the .iso file.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows installer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onwards](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No its not a silly question. :)

Ubuntu used to have a windows installer (for XP and win7) called Wubi (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Warning). With it you could install Ubuntu without the need to partition you hard disk (its main benefit). But it has been dropped starting version 13.04 and as far as I know is not being maintained.

You can still dual boot with windows. But you will have to create a separate partition on your hard disk for Ubuntu.
There are plenty of guides on the Internet on how to do that.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Not entirely true. The WUBI installer is still on the installation media and changed from a download to a clickable link on the dvd. BUT it does -not- work with W8+. ONLY 13.04 does not include it. 13.10 and 14.04 do have it on the dvd.

Comment: So basically, if i want to dual boot with windows, I have to partition my hard drive. Wubi isn't working for 14.04.1

Is that correct?

Comment: @user313550 no, it depends on the Windows you want to use it with. Windows ME and Windows 8: not going to be able to use WUBI. XP, W7: yes, it will work.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Wait, are you saying that you can use Wubi to install Ubuntu inside Windows (7 and XP) without partitioning?

Comment: @direwolf yes. That is what WUBI is about: it is a container inside a windows installation. Works with 7 and XP. Not with 8 or ME. There where problems with WUBI during our 13.04 launch (it was probably not suited for release) and got temp. dropped from the installation. They then switched from a download to a executable on the dvd.

Answer (score 1):

Download the Ubuntu iso File Extract it Find Wubi.exe in extracted folder double click it and follow on screen instructions

Answer (score 0):

You should read this page for further informations: [Ubuntu Wiki Wubi Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)