# I am unclear on this: Are WUBI Installations actually supported on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, wubi, support

I am unclear on this: Are WUBI Installations supported on Ubuntu 14.04? Yes; I know it is on the disk, but I find myself confused why it was put back on there, and questioning whether this was an accident or not. After it was taken off of 13.04, I worked under the assumption that it reached end of life, and that **people hence forth should be advised to not use it as a tool.**

Is there any official explanation?

Comment: I believe the official status is that "development has stopped", and at one point during 12.10 or 13.04 (can't remember which), Canonical had a message recommending people not to use WUBI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Bodhi.Zazen for pointing this out:

[Windows installer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onwards](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards)

Quote:

> **Support for WUBI has NOT dropped;** it is no longer the preferred method though since Windows 8 does not play nice but if you have Windows 7 or older (excluding Windows ME) all you need to do is copy the installer from the ISO and it will install.