# Not able to install ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, wubi

Error log here: http://paste.ots.me/560746

I am trying to install Ubuntu through WUBI, and am unsuccessful. I believe this is because my c: drive is corrupt, however that does not make sense to me because I have this installed on my e: drive.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Okay well due to that "bad" word someone edited my post in a really weird way.
I want ubuntu installed on C not E, its giving me an error that E is corrupt(according to the log). And my C harddrive is not corrupt.

But how can I install ubuntu while keeping windows 7 without using Wubi?

"Just install Ubuntu in virtual machine and play around with it"
Yeah I tried that after I posted this last night, diden't go that well either. The installer diden't wanna add 64bit and it diden't want to start the machine itself. Gonna take another look at it today!

Comment: This appears to be a Wubi system. Does the information in [Windows installer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onwards](http://askubuntu.com/q/449486/22949) help? Either way, you're quite unlikely to get "wubildr" errors if you uninstall Wubi and install Ubuntu the usual way (i.e., with its own partitions, rather than inside your Windows system with Wubi). See [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/q/1366), [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/22949), and [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/22949) if your computer shipped with Windows 8.

Comment: Just install Ubuntu in virtual machine and play around with it

Comment: Please refrain from using explicit language. Also; welcome to the community. To your question; try installing ubuntu without using WUBI; It will more than likely solve your issues.

Comment: Hi! We routinely edit questions, simply to tidy them up - almost every question is edited. The fact that you had the bad word made it happen quicker, but it was inevitable. I suggest you create a live CD or USB by downloading the iso, not using wubi.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need Wubi to install Ubunrtu alongside Windows. Do the following.

1. Boot Windows. Go to System Settings, find there Administration - Disk manager. This utility would allow you to shrink partitions. Shrink any and leave some free space (10Gb  to boot)
2. Reboot to Ubuntu disk and install Ubuntu to that free space.
3. Upon next reboot you will be presented a list (grub bootloader) to choose which OS to boot. Well, in 80% cases. If not, look for manual on how to restore a list, depending on what OS does boot.