# why ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso file not running when mount it on windows 7 32bit ?

Tags: wubi

I am trying to install ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso on my windows 7 32bit os but when i mount ISO file and run wubi.exe , it's not running, same problem in ubunatu 14.04.1 -desktop-i386.iso anybody please help me....i how can i fix this problem ?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you're trying to do, but [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/22949), [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/q/1366/22949), or [Windows installer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onwards](http://askubuntu.com/q/449486/22949) should help. In short, it's recommended to install alongside Windows rather than with Wubi, but if you really do want a Wubi system you can install one by copying wubi.exe and the ISO itself into a new, empty folder, and running wubi.exe.

Comment: I want to install ubuntu-13.04 inside windows 7.. ubuntu-11.10 working but  ubuntu-13.04 not working

Comment: Welcome to AU! Unfortunately Ubuntu 13.04 is [off topic here because it has reached its end of life](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/529751/edit) your question to only refer to 14.04 (or any other supported Ubuntu edition)?

Comment: @EliahKagan: Neither the question or I mentioned 12.04, I didn't mention Wubi and I never suggested the question in its entirety is off topic. I merely urged to limit the discussion to the mentioned “on topic” 14.04 release by removing the reference to 13.04.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Huh, I don't know what I was thinking. **This is my mistake.** Indeed your comment was unrelated to Wubi. (As for whether or not this question is off-topic, it mentions "same problem in ubunatu 14.04.1 -desktop-i386.iso." I don't think it's bad for a question to mention things the OP has tried that would not, by themselves, have made the question on-topic. On the other hand, the wording does suggest the OP may still be primarily focused on installing 13.04.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wubi is no longer supported as of ubuntu 12.10 (I believe) except for special situations. Instead of just mounting it like that I suggest creating a live usb or dvd and booting up a full live session.

Also, if you were trying to use wubi to install so you can use ubuntu from within windows 7 then my recommendation is to use a virtual machine as you can make a full virtualized installation from wubi.

Comment: I'm saying wubi is probably having a bug, and is no longer supported so my solution is to run a full boot.

Comment: is that hard? what computer do you have?

Comment: How can i make LIVE USB ?

Comment: you need to find a disk imager and burn the file to the disk/usb

Comment: While 13.04 and 12.10 are themselves no longer supported, [Wubi remains supported and maintained](http://askubuntu.com/a/449526/22949), though [there are good reasons to recommend most users create normal installations instead](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7596/22949). While Wubi does have quite a few bugs, in this situation `wubi.exe` is actually working as intended--it no longer offers to make a Wubi installation when run from the CD/DVD/USB itself (which includes when the image is mounted on a virtual drive). I've voted to dupe this question to one that has answers about how to install Wubi.

Comment: I had completed installation now I want to know that How to remove ubuntu 14.04 alongside alongside Windows 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Wubi. It has been discontinued as of Ubuntu 13.04. It had many bugs and was unstable in general.

However, if you really want to, you can still run Wubi. Note that you will need to have Windows 7 to run these steps. Wubi is not tested/supported on Windows 8. They do not play nice.

1. Start by copying the `Wubi.exe` file from the ISO image to your desktop.
2. Double-click it.
3. Follow the install wizard.
4. ???
5. Profit.

**If you can, always install Ubuntu on its own partition. It'll be faster, stabler, and easier to fix if problems come up. There is *no guarantee* that Wubi will work as expected (or even work at all). *You have been warned!***

Comment: While I agree it's usually much better to create a normal installation of Ubuntu, [Wubi has not been discontinued](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7596/22949) (as [has somewhat recently been discussed](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/11904/22949)).