# problem to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7

Tags: partitioning, windows-7

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 (64-bit version, from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) on my computer where Windows 7 is already installed. I would like to have both Ubuntu and Windows 7 installed on the computer. 
I have downloaded the Ubuntu, burned it to a disc, and started the installation. In step 4 where I should partition the disk I got the text "This computer currently has no detected operating system. What would you like to do?" Erase disk and install Ubuntu, or Something else. 
I am interested is it possible to easily install Ubuntu 14.04.1 alongside Windows 7 on my computer (I have limited experience with installation of operative systems), and could I install some earlier Ubuntu version without these problems?

---

The main problem is that during the installation Ubuntu couldn’t see Windows nor partitions on the disk. I have clicked on Something else, but after that on the next screen I am not asked to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. Instead, I am asked to partition the disk, and the only row that I see displays the full 500GB disk. I partitioned the disk from the Windows and released 200GB on hard disk, but even after that Ubuntu sees just full disk capacity of 500GB. If it could help, my computer is Acer Aspire E15 E5-511G and I installed Windows 7 in legacy boot mode.

Does somebody have any idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

On that screen, Click on SOMETHING ELSE.
In the next screen, Click on Install Ubuntu alongside Microsoft Windows...
Next Screen, Most likely you'll see one row showing /dev/sda  (SDA is 1'st Hard Disk).

VERY IMPORTANT,  STEP
highlight the free space row & only then Click on ADD button, enter how many GB you want for Linux.

you will see 2 extra rows now, 
Ubuntu Linux & temporary swap partition.

Hope this helps.

If you need screenshots, Plz use the below link.

http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/step-by-step-beginners-guide-to-installing-ubuntu-11-10.172128/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, the main problem is that during the installation Ubuntu couldn’t see Windows nor partitions on the disk (nor on screen 7-B nor on 7-C). I have clicked on Something else, but after that on the next screen I am not asked to install Ubuntu alongside Windows, and later the only row that I see displays the full 500GB disk. I partitioned disk from Windows and released 200GB on hard disk, but even after that Ubuntu sees just full disk capacity of 500GB. My computer is Acer Aspire E15 E5-511G and I installed Windows 7 in legacy boot mode.  (I added this in my post)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not comfortable with the partitioning you might try wubi. Check out this link [Windows installer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onwards](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to install Linpus Linux first. Then it was possible to install Ubuntu and to see partitions on the disk without problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Wubi Method Of Installation for installing Ubuntu 15.04 alongside Windows 7. In this method:

1. Open the downloaded ISO file.
2. Run Wubi.exe.
3. Select the relevant options on the Ubuntu Installer Window that open.
4. Select "Reboot Now" and Click Finish.

For more details visit this [link](http://goo.gl/7gP22t).

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu. Follow this link  from [ubunutu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)

**NOTE** : to avoid data loss Keep Important files backup

Comment: don't just copy a link into your answer (even when referring to the official Ubuntu explanation, but answer the poster's question and *ẗhen*  refer to the link of the docs.  (like the upvoted answer above)  You can delete your answer to reverse the negative points to your reputation...