# where can i download windows installer for ubuntu or wubi?

Tags: wubi

Where can i download wubi or windows installer for ubuntu?

I have search the whole ubuntu site for the download link but dint find.Then i downloaded it from few other site but all of them gave me error.

Comment: Wubi is depreciated. Why do you need it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

It should be e.g. on the  Ubuntu 14.04 iso. See also here:
[Windows installer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onwards](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards)