# (Trusty problem)When installing Ubuntu 14.04 with WUBI shows me a error!

Tags: 14.04

Here's a screenshot with the error message:

[image]

Sorry, I am Romanian . That's why is written in Romanian, but the problem has a bit of English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows installer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onwards](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards)

Comment: Avoid Wubi or try a [community supported version](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki).

Answer (score 0):

This is not the recommended way to install Ubuntu.
Installing via Wubi is known for generating issues.

Create a properly working installation media.
Create sufficient free space for Ubuntu OS.

Write the Ubuntu ISO file to a DVD or USB.
Boot from this media and install Ubuntu.

Learn more : [Ubuntu installation guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: Don't want to kill my computer with Windows, i chose WUBi because i wanted dual boot, no Bios , no complicated things.

Comment: @BooMusic : You don't kill anything when you install Ubuntu correctly to a separate partition. Choose 'Something else' when asked by the installer and select the empty partition you have created before. Ubuntu will be installed alongside Windows. :)

Comment: I was in WINDOWS, not in the Ubuntu setup! ake a closer look, its Windows.

Comment: @BooMusic : Yes I know that you are on Windows ... but as I said before : Wubi does generate huge problems - so when you want to install and use Ubuntu, you should do this the recommended way ! :)

Comment: @BooMusic: Wubi is known to generate a lot of problems, so it would probably be better if you installed Ubuntu the standard way, that does not mean things have to be complicated nor that you will have to remove Windows, if you simply boot into an Ubuntu LiveUSB and choose to dual-boot you should be able to get Windows and Ubuntu running fine side-by-side without issue **and without having to remove Windows**.

Comment: Could i do it a better way ?

Comment: Cause' im in my brother#'s computer and he let's with with wubi only!

Comment: @BooMusic : Unfortunately not ... let your brother decide if he wants to have Ubuntu or not ... and when he wants to install and use Ubuntu, he has to do it the way it has to be. :)

Comment: @BooMusic: You could install it as a Virtual Machine using [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/), then it will be completely isolated as well from your Windows machine so no matter how you install it on the virtual drive it won't be able to affect Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to install Ubuntu O.S. outside Windows O.S. Because, after launch of Ubuntu 12.04 and later version installation with wubi.exe is not working perfectly.

Comment: I don't want to, i don't want to uninstall Windows, i will get in big trouble.

Comment: Nobody suggested to uninstall Windows.

Comment: While installing Ubuntu outside Window your windows o,s will stay as it. and Ubuntu O.S will be in installed in another drive.

Both O.S can be used. At boot time you will have option to boot Ubuntu O.S or Windows O.S.