# Problem with Ubuntu 14.04 installation through wubi.exe

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, wubi

I am facing the following problem during the installation of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Wubi is not supported.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows installer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onwards](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards)

Comment: Official wubi.exe uses outdated download links. So avoid Wubi or use a [community supported version](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki#releases).

Answer (score 1):

Wubi is not the recommended way to install Ubuntu.
Also it is known to generate a lot of issues.
Install Ubuntu the recommend way.

Create a DVD/USB installation media and boot from it.
Start the installation of the Ubuntu operating system ...
You can find many answers here explaining how to do it.

Alternatively you can install Ubuntu in a virtual machine.
One very popular and well working solution is VirtualBox.
Personally I recommend to perform the normal installation.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you still have Ubuntu ISO file, open it with Winrar or a program like Winrar.
2. Export the wubi.exe to this folder (Installation folder)
3. Run the wubi.exe again.

If problem is still here, download the iso file again and try 1., 2. and 3. steps again. I hope it helps you.

**But, I recommend you a normal installation, not this.**