# I'm using ubuntu 20.04 LTS in windows 10

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnuplot

```
   G N U P L O T
    Version 5.2 patchlevel 8    last modified 2019-12-01

    Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2019
    Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

    gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
    faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
    immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')


Terminal type is now 'wxt'
gnuplot> plot sin(x)
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
19:59:45: Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?
Failed to initialize wxWidgets.

Terminal type is now 'unknown'
     wxt init failure
gnuplot>
```

Comment: If you are using original WSL, see [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux as of 2018?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-as-of-2018). Otherwise [Are there any limitations in working in Ubuntu in Windows Subsystem for Linux on Windows 10?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1247438/178692). Alternatively, set the gnuplot terminal type to one of the may file-based types (png, eps etc.) and copy the resulting file to your Windows system to display it.