# how to Run Linux software in windows (in single boot)?

Tags: windows

I want to run Windows and Linux in a single boot. I already using windows 10. Is there any software to run a Linux operating system and how?

Comment: Virtualbox for example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux as of 2018?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-as-of-2018) and [Are there any limitations in working in Ubuntu in Windows Subsystem for Linux on Windows 10?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1247438/)

Comment: Have you been satisfied with my answer? Then please give me an upvote (▲). If I could solve your problem, it would be nice if you [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/217657) my answer (✓). In the opposite case, please clarify your needs by [edit]ing or comments. See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are multiple ways. You can use [virtualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) (e.g. VirtualBox) which would allow you to use full Linux install but requires more system resources (at least disk space, RAM, and CPU power).

Or you can use some compatibility layer like [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) or [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/). This allows running some parts of the GNU/Linux system, especially the command line tools.

See also:

- [How to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/q/142549/250300)
- [Ubuntu on WSL](https://ubuntu.com/wsl)