# I'm unable to launch qemu after installation

Tags: kernel, windows-subsystem-for-linux, qemu

so i type this command in wsl `<qemu-system-x86_64>` and it should open the qemu window as usual but it doesn't instead it gives this error **Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused***
***gtk initialization failed***
kindly help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running GUI apps under WSL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1389908/running-gui-apps-under-wsl).  Also see [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/q/993225/1165986).  Thanks!

Comment: Ack to @NotTheDr01ds but if you do not want a GIU in the first place you might consider running qemus GUI frontent in another way. Look for the -display argument which allows the gui to be served via spice or vnc. Or try text on the console via `-curses` or even no graphic at all with `-nographic`. There are many options, you have to pick what suits you best.

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt Great point.  Running QEMU without the X-based GUI would be the better option under WSL on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem and fixed updating wsl from powershell,

```
wsl --update
```

also im using xming server for virtualization

Comment: I made some changes in bashrc and it worked, by the way it did run in nographic mode