# WSL: when I try to use GUI package get error "Can't open display"

Tags: display, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running through the tutorial on: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-wsl2-on-windows-11-with-gui-support#5-install-and-use-a-gui-package

After installing X11 applications I try to follow the tutorial and open `xeyes`:

```
xeyes &
```

I get the following response:

```
Error: Can't open display
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Could you run `wsl.exe --version` and add the results in an [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1449804/edit) to your question?  Also, is there any more information in the error?  If so, please copy and paste the full message.  Thanks!

Comment: I tried this, but get an error message: --version: command not found

However using a different command I can see that I am using WSL2 for Ubuntu, if helpful

Comment: Okay, so you are on a somewhat older release of WSL that doesn't support `--version`, and may not support GUI applications (if you are using Windows 10).  See [Running GUI apps under WSL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1389908/running-gui-apps-under-wsl) and my answer to a similar question for instructions on how to upgrade to the "Store" release of WSL on Windows 10.  If that solves it, let me know by clicking the "This solved my problem" in the header.  Otherwise, let me know via comment and we'll investigate further.  Thanks!

Comment: I do see that the Ubuntu tutorial includes information on installing WSL from the Store, but you may have already had an older release installed and skipped that part.

Comment: This might help. https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6430 . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61860208/running-graphical-linux-desktop-applications-from-wsl-2-error-e233-cannot-op

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem. What I did was:

1. close the terminal
2. re-open a fresh terminal
3. run `wsl --update`
4. relaunch ubuntu `ubuntu`
5. run `xeyes &`

This fixed my problem.

Comment: Alas, I tried this and it didn't solve the problem. Thanks very much for the suggestion nonetheless.

Answer (score 5):

Open `C:\Users\<username>\.wslconfig`

Find the line: `guiApplications=false` and change it to `guiApplications=true`.
If you can not find the line, add it in the file.

Restart your PC (or just do `wsl --shutdown` followed by `wsl` as suggested by @bkakilli).

Comment: Thanks. Restarting only the wsl was sufficient for me. `wsl -shutdown` then `wsl`. No need to reboot.

Comment: Thanks @bkakilli. Worked for me. This should also be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you use core i chip of F series(core i5-9400F), you must install GPU (ubutun version must be 20.04 or later)
see: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/enabling-gpu-acceleration-on-ubuntu-on-wsl2-with-the-nvidia-cuda-platform#1-overview

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday. What fixed it today was:

1. Upgrading WSL to WSL2 (https://www.scaler.com/topics/linux-terminal-for-windows/)
2. Installing Xming for Windows (https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/)

After steps 1 & 2 I still got the "Can't open display" error

3. Section 4.2 of the following article explains how to set environment variables (https://datacadamia.com/ssh/x11/display)

After confirming the shell (bash in my case), setting the DISPLAY variable with the following command enabled me to get X11 commands (e.g. xclock etc) to display in Xming:

$ export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1328549)