# How to enable GUI on wsl?

Tags: 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed wsl with Ubuntu 20.04 on windows 11. Now, it is saying that display cannot be opened after running xeyes & command. I followed this [link](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-wsl2-on-windows-11-with-gui-support#5-install-and-use-a-gui-package) on wsl posted by ubuntu.

Comment: What is the exact error given ?    Also, what is the output for: `echo $DISPLAY` ?

Comment: Did you see/read this: [WSL: when I try to use GUI package get error "Can't open display"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1449804/wsl-when-i-try-to-use-gui-package-get-error-cant-open-display) ?

Comment: Yeah! It worked. Anyways, Thanks for helping me here!