# Xdotool not displaying any results

Tags: virtualbox, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xdotool

I am a beginner to Linux and really having fun using it so far, but it seems that there is a problem I cannot solve, or at least don't quite understand -- The `xdotool` from X11 Project doesn't work on Ubuntu under either my VirtualBox installation or my Windows WSL installation.

I have done everything I can but still no luck.

- My VirtualBox Ubuntu Release is 22.10, and yes I am using Xorg not Wayland.
- In WSL, I downloaded the Xming X Server for Windows from sourceforge.com.

Here is what I did in both of them:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt  install xdotool
xdotool type "hello"
```

Nothing happens ... no errors,  nothing.

Both WSL and VirtualBox Ubuntu's have the same exact response -- Nothing.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to what's happening in your VirtualBox installation (but I suspect it's something similar).  The issue with WSL, at least, is that you don't appear to have an X application running in which to *target* the output of Xdotool.  If you do, you don't mention it, at least.

It's an easy mistake to make -- I did it myself just a few days ago when trying something out.

Just running the X server doesn't give it a target application.  You would need to be running the command above in an X *terminal application*, such as Xterm in order to see the results.

The terminal in which Ubuntu is running under WSL is *not*, of course, an X application; it's a Windows application.

Also note that you shouldn't even need Xming any more for this to work.  All recent releases of WSL support GUI applications directly.  See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1389923/1165986) for more information.  It's doubtful that the KB patch is even needed any longer, as it *should be* integrated into the mainline monthly servicing releases at this point.

With that installed, remove any changes to the `DISPLAY` variable that you put in place for Xming.  The stock WSL should manage `DISPLAY`  correctly.

Then:

```
sudo apt install xterm
```

From WSL, run `xterm`.  And *inside* that Xterm terminal, run your:

```
xdotool type "hello"
```

You should see the `Hello` entered at the next prompt-line in Xterm.

Note that, according to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/551541/432493) many applications do not accept "sent" keystrokes unless they are already the foreground application.  This is for security reasons.

Comment: I'm puzzled about the OP's lack of success in VirtualBox as well - I wonder if it's terminal dependent? It works for me in a Lubuntu 22.04 VM, with both qterminal and xterm.

Comment: I Think i broke my **Display** variable. This error keeps showing  (xterm: Xt error: Can't open display:
xterm: DISPLAY is not set)

Comment: Regarding @steeldriver. Actually xdotool worked on my VB. It appears that i had to logout of ubuntu then choose XORG before logging  back in to my account. XD

Comment: God Bless @NotTheDr01ds It works!!  Regarding my Error, IT that "**DISPLAY is not Set**", it appears there is a file, located in my root dir called  .wslconfig that contains the following: [wsl2]
guiApplications=false . i just changed it from **false** to **true**