# Dual Boot installing Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04

Dear Sir/Madam,
              How to Dual boot install Ubuntu with windows using without (VirtualBox,USB stick and CD)

Comment: If you are an expert, netinstall. If you have any further questions, then you are not an expert - you *need* either a VM, USB stick, or DVD to install Ubuntu successfully.

Answer (score -1):

use a program called [Wubi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards) to [install ubuntu](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/9142/easily-install-ubuntu-linux-with-windows-using-the-wubi-installer/#Installing_Ubuntu_from_Wubi.exe) straight  from you windows GUI .

(No ISO, USB, or virtualization required.

Comment: PS this  program old & does not support ubuntu 16.06