# Install Lumbuntu from inside Windows OS?

Tags: usb, windows, lubuntu, cd-drive

I'm trying to revitilize an old P4 desktop w/1.25GB of RAM.  The BIOS does not have any option to boot from USB.  The CD/DVD for whatever reason does not recognize the Lubuntu (and other Linux distros) DVDs that I burned.  I tried using a boot manager DVD to launch the USB installer - that also did not work.  The CD/DVD does recognize Windows based CDs, not sure why.  So my question - I have Windows XP running on this machine - is there any method of launching the Lumbuntu installer from inside the Windows OS ?  I want to wipe XP off the box, not duel boot.   Any suggestions would be appreciated.   Thank you !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows installer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onwards](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards)

Comment: I agree with @Compatico's answer, in that its likely that your optical drive is CDR only (though some p4 era drives would only read certain media; eg. specific colors though it wasn't the color but the type of film on the disc that caused us to see different colors).  I'd suggest using a text installer (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) then add `lubuntu-desktop` to it (during or after install) turning it into Lubuntu 18.04 LTS (or 18.10).

Comment: If you can boot from CD (not DVD) then burning a Plop bootable CD will work. You also need the usual USB with the OS installer the will be booted from inside the plop's menu.

Comment: You can put plop boot manager on your hard drive if it does not work on your computer as a floppy or CD. You can install Lubuntu to your HDD using a friends computer, (in BIOS mode). EasyBCD will install grub on your Windows disk you can boot The Lubuntu USB installer from there.

Answer (score 0):

The drive is probably just a CDR/RW burner and can't read DVD. If so you need to find an image that is smaller than 700MB to find on a CD. Check the Lubuntu download pages for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the response - It's definitely a DVD/CD-Rom drive and I did tried booting Puppy Linux on a CD and that also did not read - The boot manager program PLOP was also burned to CD and was unable to be read.  The drive works with Windows 7 and Server 2003