# How do I install Kubuntu with WUBI on another drive (a second one)

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, wubi

I want to install Kubuntu with WUBI on my second drive. but it doesnt seem to work

When turn on the machine it by defaultly asks me to select a os, I picked Kubuntu and when it booted it says:
"Try hd(0,0): NTFS5: No wubildr"
Is there any solution for this? The drive doesnt have any os on it installed expect the Kubuntu

Comment: WUBI was discontinued in 2012. You will have to boot Kubuntu from a live USB and install it on the other drive.

Comment: I have used the one that is on github (https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/issues) is it the old one?

Comment: Please open an issue in the GitHub page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows installer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onwards](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards)